# Update rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to update my `DataGridView`. I can just only update one row but when i try to update two rows they give me a error:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint "

```
string strPRSconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POSdb"].ConnectionString;
        string date = dt_date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var counter = 1;
            SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(strPRSconn);
            sc.Open();
            counter++;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

            if (!row.IsNewRow)
            {

                    string strQry = "UPDATE CounterChecking "+
                    "SET part_no = @c0,po_no = @po_no,invoice = @invoice,part_name = @c1,"+
                    "date = @date,color = @c2,qty_ordered = @c3,qty_for_delivery = @c4,qty_recieved = @c5,"+
                    "variance = @c6,unit_price = @c7, total = @c8, remarks = @c9 "+
                    "WHERE po_no= '" + cb_po_search.Text + "'";
                    SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strQry, sc);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c0", counter);
                    counter++;
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@po_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_ponumber2.Text;
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_invoice2.Text;
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", row.Cells[1].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", row.Cells[2].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", row.Cells[3].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", row.Cells[4].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", row.Cells[5].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", row.Cells[6].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c7", row.Cells[7].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c8", row.Cells[8].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c9", row.Cells[9].Value);
                    scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sc.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated!");}
        }
    }
```

Comment: which field is your primary key?

Comment: You are trying to set the same value for the primary key for the database table. It must be unique. I imagine po_no is your primary key since you specified it in the WHERE clause. Remove it from the UPDATE part of the statement and you should be good.

Comment: po_no is just a Foreign Key. my primary key is the part_name

Comment: what do i put in my sql statement?

Comment: can u code it? I'm a little confuse. thank you.

Comment: wait sir my PK is part_no FK po_no FK invoice

Comment: part_name is not PK sorry my mistake

Comment: how you are getting part_no, from the user? if it is so restrict the user to type same part_no in two row as because it is ur Primary key

Comment: they are just inputting. but why only i can add only 1 row? can u put a sample code?

Comment: `var i=1;` before the foreach loop and then inside loop  `scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c0", i); i++;`